# Logical Operators and Initialization in a variable

Tags: c, logical-operators

What is the concept behind expressions like this?

```
int x;
x=7||6;
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: The concepts are mentioned in the question itself. Hint: Its not the initialisation part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because for homework question you should show at least minimal effort to solve it

Comment: `7` and `6` as a logical value evaluate to true, and then `true` cast to an `int` is `1`

Comment: @Slava this does not look like homework to me

Comment: @tobi303 before edit question was "OUTPUT: 1 What is the concept behind it?????? Kindly solve my problem." sounds like a homework for me

Comment: Where is the output coming from? I see no code to produce any output.

Comment: so was this in a code? or is this an example from book?

Comment: "expressions like this" will have different behaviors if instead of `int`s, the values are variables. Consider `x=a||b`, given C's Short-Circuit Evaluation. If `a` is non-zero, then its value will be assigned to `x`, and evaluation ceases. On the other hand, if `a == 0`, then the `or` operation will move on and evaluate the next clause, and assign its result to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

From the C11 draft specification

> **6.5.14 Logical OR operator**
>
> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So in the expression `x = 7||6;`, the `||` yields 1 because at least one (in fact both) of the operands compare unequal to 0.

Comment: What if i use type casting

Comment: Thank you and we cannot use type casting right???

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;
x=7||6;             // it is true always .
```

The output `1`, you get is due to bool is promoted to `int` . As you can assume -

```
true==1
```

Comment: What does the update suppose to mean?

Comment: @SergeyA  I don't follow .Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, but bool is __not__ promoted to int. Bool **IS** int in C, with ==0 meaning false and <>0 meaning true.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  Question is tagged as both `C` and `C++` . And AFAIK , `bool` is a fundamental datatype in C++ . And converting `true` to `int` will yield `1`.

Comment: Then the answer is only valid for C++.

Comment: `true==1` is a logical test expression. What can I assume about it?

Comment: Sry for late reply.....My questions was why cannot we use type casting in the given problem??

Comment: @VarunSaproo No need . Even if you do it will be `int` .

Comment: If i want to do in float  say float x ;           x=7.65||6.86      Will 7.65 and 6.86 be considered same as that 7 and 6 in the above given problem. Here we considered 7 and 6 as true???

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 7 || 6;
x = 7 "or" 6; //or can only apply to booleans
x = true or true; //Auto cast to booleans
x = true;
x = 1; //Auto cast to int
```

And please do some minimal effort in your class problems....

Comment: There is no cast to int. There is no cast to boolean. int **IS** boolean.